# c# WebClient call works in .NET 3.5 but not in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, webclient

Using VS2010, I have the following issue.  When building this against .NET 3.5, it works fine.  When building against .NET 4.0, we get an error.

```
string url = "http://internal_url";
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
wb.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wb.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET LR 1.0.3705;)");
Stream stream = wb.OpenRead(url);
```

This fails with an "Unable to connect to the remote server" in .NET 4.0.  Once again, it works fine in .NET 3.5.  I've tried using my credentials in place of the default credentials, but that didn't work either.  This is an internal server we're trying to connect to.

Anyone have any ideas on what I could do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a proxy issue with our global setup.

I got more information after the solution was discovered.  This code worked at our corporate HQ (based in a European country) no matter the .NET version, but not in the US.  The reason was because of a firewall setting that made the default credentials not acceptable in .NET 4.0.  Once the IP of the correct proxy was entered into the code, it worked from the US.

It also turned out that it worked in .NET 3.5 on only some machines here in the US.  This solution makes it work in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.  We've decided that trying to figure out why there was the discrepancy between versions is not a task that we want to run to ground.

Long story short - if you run into this issue, check proxy settings and look into using the IP address of your proxy rather than defaulting it.